# What are the minimum requirements to run a graphical application?

Tags: debian, xorg, virtualbox

This follows my [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/27585/13396), where I installed Debian for the purpose of having a lightweight distro to run virtual machines on.  I installed it with just the laptop and admin packages -- *not* anything graphical.

I've installed VirtualBox and xorg.  I cloned a VM from another hard drive, and registered it successfully.  When I try to start the device (still from the console) it complains about being unable to create frame buffers.  Sorry I can't copy and paste the long error message, but it's not really feasible at this point.

I figure this is because I don't have any window manager of any kind.  If possible I would like to keep it that way.  I will have no reason to minimize, resize, reposition, or close VirtualBox. I just need the VM to take up my entire screen as if the screen was a window.

> #### What are the minimum requirements to run graphical applications on Linux?
>
> - What software do I need to install?
> - What command would I need to run to get my desired result?

All answers and links will be appreciated!

---

*Update:*

I wasn't very clear about my something earlier.  I'm trying to run it via [VBoxSDL](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/vboxsdl-the-simplified-vm-displayer-for-virtualbox.html).  I think it'll lower the requirements.  From that page it says...

> VBoxSDL does indeed only provide a simple window that contains only
>   the “pure” virtual machine, without menus or other controls to click
>   upon and no additional indicators of virtual machine activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a premise, I want to remember that the **host** machine is the real machine on which runs `VirtualBox`, while the **guest** machine is the *virtual* machine that runs inside `VirtualBox` (I see some confusion on this point in the question and in some comment).

You need an X11 server (e.g. X.org X11 implementation) on your **host** machine to run `VirtualBox` application. `VirtualBox` opens an X11 *client* windows on the **host** to display the console of the **guest**.

On your **guest** machine (i.e. inside your *virtual box*), an X11 server could be needed if you have to run a *graphical* application on the **guest** console.

You can avoid to **run** an X11 server on the **host** machine using `VBoxHeadless` command but, in any case, you need to install X11 libraries on the **host**. If you use `VBoxHeadless`, the **guest** will run as you have no monitor connected to, so you'll can not see the **guest** console.

Using `VBoxManage` you can modify your virtual box configuration to activate remote display, this way you'll can display the **guest** console on a remote machine (running an X11 server) using `rdesktop` application.

You can find the procedure to create a **guest** that you can control by a remote machine on an headless **host** in [Chapter 7](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html) of VirtualBox manual.

Note that you need to install the [VirtualBox Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) to use *VRDP*.

Comment: Thank you!  I was just putting the pieces together when I saw your answer.  It turns out that all I needed to do was run `startx` and then the commands that were failing.  I have my virtual machine up and running right now.  All the other information (especially `rdesktop`) I'll need to look at in some more depth.

Answer (score 2):

You problem here is that *"graphical applications"* does *not* have a single, clear meaning on unix boxen.

- Probably it means a program that requires X, so you'll have to install X11.
- Only, it *might* mean a program that uses [SVGAlib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SVGALib) and runs from the text console. Or it could use [aalib](http://aa-project.sourceforge.net/aalib/) and run in any terminal.
- If it runs in X it probably needs one of more of qt, gnome, kde, xfce, fltk, mosaic, ... all of which are (at least) widgit libraries (some of these are much more than that). You'll need every one of these that your programs require. (Some programs can work with more than one.)
- Some may require [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) or some other compatibility layer. If so, you'll need those too...

Taking care of all these dependencies is a big part of what package-managers do and a big part of the add value that distributions bring.

In debian you would just ask aptitude to install the program you want and it will find all the necessary dependencies. Or you could use apt directly, and it will *tell* you what dependencies are not satisfied and you can install them first.

Comment: The application is Virtual Box.  It requires SDL, which I have installed.  It can [work with just SDL](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/vboxsdl-the-simplified-vm-displayer-for-virtualbox.html), which is the version I am trying to use.  I installed xorg, is X11 a different package?

Comment: X.org is the most common X11 implementation these days. To the point that you rarely hear of any others.

Comment: I installed VirtualBox with `apt-get`.  So that probably means I have everything I need installed... but not necessarily running, right?  What needs to be running?